# How do I play a music/track with Spotify web API in the links

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api, spotify

I'm struggling a lot with APIs since I'm just a beginner at it. I just want the API of Spotify musics however I already know how to search there albums and etc. This is my code provided below..

This is my access token for the Spotify API:

```
const CLIENT_ID = "xxxxx"
const CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxx"
```

And what you see here is the list of albums,
but you can also see the musics API in the end code of this second snippet.

I'm trying to pass the specific music that I will click.
`var playmusics = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player')`

However I don't understand how I will specifically get the API there and how I will play a music there...

There is a tutorial I saw but I don't want to authenticate in button since that is not my goal..

(because It is already authenticate in the `useEffect(())`)
..You can see it here [LINK](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-spotify-player-with-react-in-15-minutes-7e01991bc4b6)...

What my real goal is just I automatically access to the Spotify player and once I click the item it will just play the music that I click in specific item.

```
... 
  const [searchInput,setSearchInput] = useState("")
  const [accessToken,setAccessToken] = useState("")
  const [albums,setAlbums] = useState([])
  const [musics,setMusics] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    var authParameters = {
      method: "POST",
      headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      body:`grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}`
    }
    
    fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",authParameters)
      .then( res => res.json())
      .then( res => {
        setAccessToken(res.access_token)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[])

  async function search() {
    console.log("Searching..." + searchInput)

    var Parameters = {
      method:"GET",
      headers:{ 
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + accessToken
      }
    }
    
    var albums = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=${
      searchInput
    }&type=album`,Parameters)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => { 
        setAlbums(res.albums.items)
      })
  
     // Here I want to access the API of player musics but it must be the same as setAlbums 
      var playmusics = await fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player')
      setMusics("Whatever inside here")
    }
...
```

And for the UI component just check all my codes here at my codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-khorana-51w7h1?file=/src/App.js

Just get your `Client_ID` and `Client_secret` on your own, at the [WEB SPOTIFY](https://developer.spotify.com/)

Comment: You can't use the player endpoint without authenticating the user, so you can't use client credentials for this.

Comment: No that's no what I'm talking about just test it yourself in my codesandbox so you'll understand what I mean...

Comment: Plus what do I mean about authenticating is not by pressing a button but just automatically it authenticate with `useEffect()` that's what I mean.

Comment: just check it again @VincentvanLeeuwen

Comment: The console says "Invalid access token" after I hit search.

Comment: You need to put your client id and client secret and everything will be alright.

Comment: otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Got you. Sorry for not reading. The only problem is that Spotify reacts the connection when I click a link. That's maybe a bug in the codesandbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247406/discussion-between-vincent-van-leeuwen-and-myth-vince).

Comment: yeah btw can you remove the votedown? It's quite uncomfortable to me though.

Comment: The votedown isn't mine, but I was thinking about giving one, because you don't follow the tutorial you've linked.

Comment: I have added an alternative to my solution that maybe doesn't request the user to log into your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific links that will play the album directly after clicking on it: [demo link](https://open.spotify.com/track/0dEIca2nhcxDUV8C5QkPYb?context=spotify:album:4m2880jivSbbyEGAKfITCa&go=1)

```
https://open.spotify.com/track/0dEIca2nhcxDUV8C5QkPYb?context=spotify:album:4m2880jivSbbyEGAKfITCa&go=1
https://open.spotify.com/track/ID_FIRST_TRACK?context=spotify:album:ALBUM_ID&go=1
```

And as I mentioned in the comments and [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247406/discussion-between-vincent-van-leeuwen-and-myth-vince): if you want [player functionality](https://developer.spotify.com/console/player/), you must [authenticate the user](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) and use [the right scope(s)](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/scopes/). Authenticating the client is not enough, as you can read in the following quote:

> Since the [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/) does not include authorization, only endpoints that do not access user information can be accessed.

Addition 1: in the [tutorial you've linked](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-spotify-player-with-react-in-15-minutes-7e01991bc4b6) it is even showing an image (I added below) were you can read "User: Log in, authorize access" [image: image from the linked tutorial]

Addition 2: What you can do is using [Embeds](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/embeds/). Using an Embed, you can add a podcast, an album, or other audio content on your website that your users can listen to. Note: the user needs to have Premium and needs to be logged into the Spotify website to play the tracks fully.